# Single server / instance mongodb deployment

Tags: mongodb

I need a database for backends (for iOS apps). Those are mostly low-load demand applications and I like mongo for it's schemaless-ness. I'm looking to host both db and app server on a small digital-ocean instances.

I plan to:

- run it under systemctl on debian probably
- have periodic backups (not sure yet how)
- make sure it's only accessible to localhost

Anything else I need to do, like maybe enable journaling? (if yes, how do I do it?). What else do I need to do so that my single-server mongod production deployment is decent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you want to deploy single instance of MongoDB for production.  This is the the recommendation from MongoDB.

> Use standalone instances for testing and development. Do not use these
>   deployments, which lack replication and high availability, for
>   production systems. For all production deployments use replica sets.

Details about installing MongoDB community edition [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/administration/install-community/).

Details about backup [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/backups/).

To enable journaling, start mongod with the `--journal` command line option.
For 64-bit builds of mongod, journaling is enabled by default.

Details about journaling [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-journaling/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and links. I know their recommendation but I don't need high-availability and replication, I want small single-server deployment. Like one can do with mysql and add replicas later when needed.

Comment: I did get that from your question but still wanted to mention.  You should be able to set up single-server following those links.

Comment: Thank you. I've read the docs and still don't get it: should I enable journaling for single-server deployment? If I should, how do I do that? I know how to enable it in write operation via `j:true`, but can't see how to enable journaling for entire db. Anything else I need to do so that my deployment is fine?

Comment: Edited my answer. Looks good to me. Make sure backup is copied to different location in case you loose your storage (if that is important in your case).